# Simpler way for multiple 'or' statements with a single variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following if statement (except the final one would be much longer with more values) that I would like to condense.

```
if ($row['titleId'] == '123' || $row['titleId'] == '456' || $row[){
```

I would imagine it would end up something like:

```
if ($row['titleId'] == ('123'||'456'){}
```

Or would I be better off like this:

```
$array = ('123','456')
if (in_array($row['titleId'], $array){}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `switch` for this:

```
switch ($row['titleId']) {
    case '123': case '456': case '789': case '314': case '271':
        doSomething();
}
```

I'd probably still prefer to have each `case` on a separate line but, if your goal is to reduce the "height" of your code, you can do it as above.

---

In terms of shortening the code in your comment, which apparently looks like this:

```
switch($row['titleId']){
    case '8216': case '8678': case '8705': case '8216': case '8707': 
        $rows[$row['titleId']]=array();
        break;
    case '8214':
        $rows['8216'][]=$row['titleId'];
        break;
    case '8791':
        $rows['8678'][]=$row['titleId'];
        break;
    case '8643':
        $rows['8705'][]=$row['titleId'];
        break;
    case '8666':
        $rows['8707'][]=$row['titleId'];
        break;
}
```

you could opt for something like:

```
$xlat = array('8214'=>'8216', '8791'=>'8678', '8643'=>'8705', '8666'=>'8707');
switch($row['titleId']){
    case '8216': case '8678': case '8705': case '8216': case '8707': 
        $rows[$row['titleId']]=array(); break;
    default:
        if (array_key_exists($row['titleId'],$xlat)) {
            $rows[$xlat[$row['titleId']]][]=$row['titleId'];
        }
}
```

This compresses the common cases by putting them under the control of an associative array. Basically, if the title ID is *in* the array as a key, its lookup value will be used to affect the correct `$rows` entry.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the full code, can you see how I can shorten it any further?

Comment: `switch($row['titleId']){
  case '8216': case '8678': case '8705': case '8216': case '8707': 
  $rows[$row['titleId']]=array();
  break;
  
  case '8214':
  $rows['8216'][]=$row['titleId'];
  break;
  
  case '8791':
  $rows['8678'][]=$row['titleId'];
  break;
  
  case '8643':
  $rows['8705'][]=$row['titleId'];
  break;
    
  case '8666':
  $rows['8707'][]=$row['titleId'];
  break;
  }`

Comment: @user1872809: see the update. I haven't tested it thoroughly but hopefully you'll get the idea.